# Issue in launching game in Amazon store

Tags: unity, c#, android, configuration

I developed a 2D game in Unity3D for Android. I tried to Release the game in the Play store and Amazon app store. In the Play Store, it's working fine. When comes to the Amazon store the game is not publishing. It gets continuously rejected at the time of review done by the amazon team. They are telling the game is not installing on the Amazon Fire tablet. I tested it in the Android tablets and Emulators it's working fine.

My Setup:
Min API Level - 22
Target API Level - Highest installed(Level 28)

I am using Unity version 2020.3.8f1

[image: configuration screen]

Anybody, please help me to solve this issue.

Update 1:
These are the issue details I received from amazon.
[image]

[Click here to view the log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e72yXzsgO5ZO6DJGAww0u40JNJGWlf74/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Did they give you any additional feedback about the installation failure like error messages, etc?

Comment: Details are updated please check